# wordpress remove "Pages" from wp_list_pages

Tags: php, wordpress, codex

Here's my code:

```
<div>
    <?php
        $pageID = 11;
        $Xpost = get_post($pageID);
        $args = array (
            "child_of" => $Xpost->ID, 
            'title-li' => ""
        );
        wp_list_pages($args); 
    ?>
</div>
```

And yet when it displays it still shows up like an unordered list with "Pages" as the title--I can't figure it out.

I even tried to change the label by putting `"title-li" => "Stuff"` or *anything* but I can't get it to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`title_li` should be an underscore not a dash